# this.props shows as undefined in an arrow function within React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am using an arrow function to bind `this` inside a React component. Please see the `handleChange()` function below. When I put a breakpoint inside the arrow function, I find something very strange: `this` is defined, but `this.props` is `undefined`. In spite of all this, `this.props.onChange()` is properly invoked!!! Is there an explanation for this strange behavior?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { someProp } = this.props;

        // <TextField> is an input component from Material UI library
        return (
            <TextField
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        );
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.props.onChange(value);
    };
}
```

P.S. On the other hand, the `render()` method behaves normally - `this.props` is defined.

**Update**

Here's the transpiled code produced by Babel:

```
_this.handleChange = function(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    _this.props.onChange(value);
}
```

Comment: please show how `handleChange` is being called

Comment: @FuzzyTree, I updated the code to show how `handleChange` is being called.

Comment: Have you looked at the code that is actually executed (i.e. the transpiled code)? The transpiled code probably doesn't use `this`.

Comment: What babel preset are you using?

Comment: @nem035, here are my Babel presets: "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1", "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1", "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3", "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1"

Comment: @FelixKling, I updated the question with the transpiled code

Comment: And you can see that the function used `_this` to refer to the component instance, not `this`.

Comment: Correct @FelixKling. I was doing source level debugging in Chrome and it never occurred to me to look at the transpiled code! Will have to remember that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More likely than not, you're being tricked by babel.

Since you're using a babel-preset < 2017, the transpilled code for:

```
class A {
  method = () => {
    this.prop.a();
  };
}
```

would [look something like](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oFsCmAXAFgewBNoBeaACgEoSA-RFVaXASwgDoAHAJz3dbEoDc9AL5DhQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1&targets=Node-8&version=6.26.0):

```
var A = function A() {
  var _this = this;

  this.method = function () {
    _this.prop.a();
  };
};
```

Looking at the code above, both `_this` and `this` within `method` are seemingly pointing to the class instance (because [`this` in a function called as a method of an object binds to that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)).

However, in JS [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a [dynamic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) so we cannot statically determine its value in a predictable fashion just by reading the code; we have to run it.

This means that the `this` inside `handleChange` isn't necessarily the same `this` you're expecting. It depends on how `handleChange` is called. However, no matter how we call `handleChange`, `_this` won't be affected (hence one reason why Babel does this)

In your particular code, you are passing `handleChange` to the `onChange` event handler for `TextField`, which will override `this` to be `undefined` by default.

React event handlers override the context to `undefined` (by [calling the handler as a plain function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call)):

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <input onChange={logThis} placeholder="Start typing" />,
  document.querySelector('#example')
)

function logThis() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

This means that in `handleChange`, `this` is bound by whatever `TextField` sets it to while `_this` still points to the instance of `MyComponent`.

Hence everything still works (because `_this` is correct), but `this` is most likely `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Very much appreciated! It all makes sense now.

Comment: Glad to help 